Tuba BBb troubles
I have found that many notes included in the JW pepper “Star Wars saga” are far too low for me to play.
I understand the need for improving the upper range before the lower and my upper notes have perfect tone already so I am worried with my lack of progress in the lowers.
I cannot play beneath a low Eb. I worry that I am too small to physically contain enough air in my lungs.

If you really can't play notes below low E-flat then you have two choices: leave them out, or play them an octave higher where they'll be much stronger. Keep doing that until you get them working.
If you feel that you are physically to small to play the low notes of the BBb tuba you might want to reconsider if that is the right instrument for you. Maybe you would have more success playing a smaller instrument like an F tuba.
